# How to set viewing window in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I made a graph in ggplot2 and I would like to zoom in the x-axis of the viewing window to min=40 and max=60. What I have now for "scale_y_continuous" changes the labels to range from 40-60, but the actual graph remains the same. Here is my code, any help would be appreciated!

```
library("ggplot2")
a<- ggplot(data=means_sort, aes(reorder(means_sort$nicknames, 
means_sort$pcts), y=means_sort$pcts))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  xlab("X") +
  ylab("Y")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(40), max(60), by = 5),1))
```

[image: Bar Graph]

Comment: Please add the input sample data, what you have got with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scale_x_continuous(limits = c(40, 60))` or `coord_fixed(xlim = c(40, 60))` might be useful in your case.

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
p
```

[image]

```
p + coord_fixed(xlim=c(15,20))
```

[image]

```
p + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(15,20))
```

[image]

Based on OP's request:

```
p + coord_flip(ylim=c(2,5))
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to carry over a coord_flip with the coord_lim? It works, but I am also trying to implement a coordinate flip so the bar graph becomes horizontal, and when I do that it doesn't carry both over.

Comment: That worked. I ended up using `a+coord_flip(ylim=c(40,60))`. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried to mimic the same with the sample dataset.